# Unity WebCamTexture input frame-rate over 30fps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam, frame-rate

I am working on a project to track a smartphone screen via 4 ArUco markers attached to the corners of the phone. The tracking algorithm is already implemented and working well. **My current issue is the frame-rate of the input: For tracking, I'm aiming for a maximal input rate, but can't get it over 30fps**.

---

**Setup:**

For tracking, I use the *Logitech StreamCam* which is capable of delivering **1920x1080@60fps**. Since the StreamCam only has a USB-C cable and my motherboard doesn't have USB-C, I'm using a [GRAUGEAR](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B09L52FYKC?ref_=pe_27091401_487187591_302_E_DDE_dt_1) USB-C to USB 3.1 adapter (for anybody else working with an adapter and the StreamCam: make sure to try and plug your webcam cable both ways into the adapter, for some reason one side only gives me FHD@30fps!).

I checked the performance by recording a short video on two devices, the PC with the USB adapter and my laptop with built-in USB-C. On the PC, I got 52fps, while only 33fps on the laptop (it's considerably weaker than my PC tho). So in theory, with the adapter setup, I should be able to get relatively close to a 60fps output if my method of testing makes sense :).

---

**Code**:
To get the input video, I'm using Unity's *WebCamTexture*. I'm using the following constructor:

```
m_webCamDevice = WebCamTexture.devices[0];
m_webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture(m_webCamDevice.Value.name, 1920, 1080, 60);

// Also tried setting requestedFPS without success
m_webCamTexture.requestedFPS = 60;

m_webCamTexture.Play();
```

This does indeed give me a WebCamTexture with FHD resolution, but the frame-rate never seems to exceed 30fps. I also tried different resolutions (e.g. 640x360@30, 1280x720@60, 1920x1080@60...) but none of them exceeded 30fps either.
I'm running the script in an otherwise empty benchmarking project without the tracking algorithm.
For benchmarking the fps, I use the following code:

```
private void Update()
    {
        dt += Time.deltaTime;
        absoluteTime = Time.time;
        
        UpdateFPS();
    }

private void UpdateFPS()
    {
        if (!webCamTexture.didUpdateThisFrame) return;

        frameCount++;
        frameCountTotal = webCamTexture.updateCount;

        fps_amortized = webCamTexture.updateCount / Time.time;
        if (dt > 1.0 / updateRate)
        {
            fps = frameCount / dt;
            if (fps_text) fps_text.text = $"({fps:F}fps)"; // Show fps in UI
            frameCount = 0;
            dt -= 1.0 / updateRate; // keep the slight overhead from the delta in comparison to the update rate (e.g.: 0.276 > 0.25 -> dt = 0.026)
        }
    }
```

---

**Questions**:

1. Did anybody manage to get an input frame-rate higher than 30fps?
2. How do you use WebCamTexture.requestedFPS correctly?
3. Is there maybe a different and more performant way other than WebCamTexture to get the WebCam input?

---

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Sounds like 720p vs 720i problem. Can you confirm you're doing full frame or interlaced @ 60 Hz and see if your camera is set up accordingly?

Comment: How would I go about checking if it's interlaced? Also so far I've only heard about that in the context of TV or e.g. GIFs and not camera input, but I don't know all that much about it to be honest

Comment: A lot of hardware still support the i (i = interlaced) modes. However, a glance at the logitec website reveals it capable of doing 1080p @ 60 Hz (https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/webcams/streamcam.960-001289.html) ... which is good news in a way - now the question remains: how to set it in that mode

Comment: btw: are you sure the benchmark loop runs at a sufficiently high frequency?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I didn't know that ^^... but yeah, I have the feeling Unity's API regarding the implementation of the WebCamTexture might be the problem

The loop should also run sufficiently often, I checked the amount of loop runs where the WebCamTexture gets updated (that's why I added the .didUpdateThisFrame check) and it's only a fraction of all loops per second